# How do I change data type of column in Apache Phoenix without losing HBase data?

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I have an HBase installation with a bunch of existing tables, with a bunch of data in them (which I would like not to be deleted). I recently came across using Apache Phoenix to be able to query HBase data with a SQL-like syntax, and so far it is brilliant. However, since I'm still not entirely familiar with the various data types and how they map to Java types that I stored in HBase, sometimes I get it wrong. If I had an HBase column that I stored as

```
Bytes.toBytes(Long long)
```

and I accidentally created my Phoenix column as a varchar, how can I now change the Phoenix column without losing all my data? If I do

```
alter table "mytable" add "myfamily"."mycolumn" unsigned_long
```

and then

```
alter table "mytable" drop column "mycolumn"
```

and then afterwards

```
alter table "mytable" add "myfamily"."mycolumn" varchar
```

all of my HBase data gets wiped from the underlying "mycolumn" column! What is the best way to get around this?

I read about setting the parameter

```
phoenix.schema.dropMetaData
```

to false, which sounds like exactly what I want, but I can't figure out where I actually set this. Is there some command I can issue in Squirrel when logged on to Phoenix to set this to false? Or is it an environment variable?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT 1**

I created a dummy table in Phoenix with a column of each type, and then looked it up in the system.catalog table to get the number to represent each data type. I then used the following command

```
upsert into system.catalog (table_name, column_name, column_family, data_type) values ('mytable','mycolumn','mycf',3)
```

to change the type of mycolumn to a decimal. However, when I query mytable, mycolumn is still of type unsigned_long. Maybe after updating this value I need to restart HBase?

FYI:

```
COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE
MYTINYINT   -6
MYBIGINT    -5
MYDECIMAL   3
MYINTEGER   4
MYFLOAT 6
MYDOUBLE    8
MYUINTEGER  9
MYULONG 10
MYUTINYINT  11
MYVARCHAR   12
ROWID   12
MYUFLOAT    14
MYUDOUBLE   15
MYBOOLEAN   16
MYUTIME 18
MYUDATE 19
MYUTIMESTAMP    19
MYDATE  91
MYTIME  92
MYTIMESTAMP 93
```

**EDIT 2**

It appears to be possible to get rid of a table from Phoenix without touching the underlying HBase table by deleting all the entries for the table from SYSTEM.CATALOG and SYSTEM.STATS. The table can then be recreated with the desired column types. No idea yet if this might have any horrific adverse effects on my HBase table!

Answer (score 1):

Phoenix stores the metadata of all the tables in another HBase table called SYSTEM_CATALOG . The parameter
  `phoenix.schema.dropMetaData`
forces the metadata to be deleted from the catalog table when an ALTER command is given.

If you set it to false, the next time you create a table with the same name, you will keep getting TableAlreadyExistsException.

Comment: In the SYSTEM.CATALOG table, I can see a column called DATA_TYPE - is it possible to just edit the value in this column manually or is this table read-only? Also, the values appear to be stored as integers (eg 12 = varchar, 16 = boolean) is there a guide anywhere for the integer to data type mappings? (I can always check the source code but it's easier if it's on a nice web page :))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can drop that column first, then add new one with the same name.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DROP COLUMN columnname;
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD columnname varchar(100);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if you are using a table rather than a view, dropping the column will wipe all the data from that column...